# Where can I find my applications in LinkedIn profile

Tags: github, linkedin

In my LinkedIn profile, I am trying to add [GitHub](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/35174/26760) application. When I tried, LinkedIn is showing Error

> You have reached the limit of applications on your homepage, please remove an application from your homepage before adding another.

When I searched Online for solution, I got this [link](http://www.linkedin.com/answers/using-linkedIn/ULI/1048649-17272462) which is stating that

> You can have a total of 15 modules and/or applications on your profile and 6 on your home page. A message bar will appear at the top of the page if you need to remove an application before adding another.

This (GitHub) was my first application I was trying to add.. I don't know why the error is showing..

Thinking that maybe my application usage is over.. I had look at my application side(which is visible at the bottom of the profile). It is empty.

Where can I find my applications? If they are installed as LinkedIn is stating.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LinkedIn announced that they **[shut down the GitHub application](http://thenextweb.com/apps/2012/11/26/linkedin-quietly-discontinues-github-app-to-better-invest-resources-into-other-projects/)**, as of 26 November 2012. Now, LinkedIn only offers this, for **[sharing from Github](http://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5067)**:

> You still have the option to share your code from GitHub on LinkedIn
>   by sharing links on your homepage or in groups.

In other words, you can share links from Github the same way that you share links from anywhere else online. That is just the same old, manual feature as in the past.